# Issue: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django

so I'm currently writing a function to let the user write a review. Tho I'm having issues when the user goes to submit the review. It tells me that

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I know that it is a very simple issue, but I cant really see the solution

The TracBack is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/webster00/products/views.py", line 84, in submit_review
    review = ReviewRating.objects.get(user=request.user.userprofile, product_id=product_id)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

During handling of the above exception (ReviewRating matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/webster00/products/views.py", line 99, in submit_review
    data.save()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /products/submit_review/6/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Here is the code

Views.py:

```
def product_detail(request, product_id):
    """ A view to show individual product details """

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(product_id=product.id, status=True)
    
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'reviews': reviews,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/product_detail.html', context)


def submit_review(request, product_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            review = ReviewRating.objects.get(user=request.user.userprofile, product=product_id)
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been updated')
            return redirect(url)
        except ReviewRating.DoesNotExist:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data = ReviewRating()
                data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
                data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                data.product_id = product_id
                data.user_id = request.user.id
                data.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submited.')
                return redirect(url)
```

Models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    wheight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=1)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

If im missing to give you some info please do tell me. Im still getting to know stack

Comment: Did you mean `product_id=product_id`? It looks like you may be trying to compare the `product` (foreign key object) to the `product_id` (integer identifier) in your query.

Comment: Yeah so what i need to do is querying the database for the product first. then pass that when getting the review: I tried product_id=product_id, but I'm getting the same error message

Comment: One guy told me to do this: 
**You can try querying the database for the product first:

product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

then you can pass that when getting your review:

review = ReviewRating.objects.get(user=request.user.userprofile, product=product)**

But I don't really understand that

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For the traceback, it looks like you should click "Switch to copy-and-paste view". I'm not sure how to format the part in yellow -- maybe a bulleted list with code formatting as needed, or you could try putting it into [Paste to Markdown](https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/) and see what it produces.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im still new so I'm still getting the hang of it! Thanks!!